# How to dynamically generate parallel futures with for-yield

Tags: scala, future, yield

I have below code:

```
  val f1 = Future(genA1)
  val f2 = Future(genA2)
  val f3 = Future(genA3)
  val f4 = Future(genA4)

val results: Future[Seq[A]] = for {
  a1 <- f1
  a2 <- f2
  a3 <- f3
  a4 <- f4
} yield Seq(a, b, c, d)
```

Now I have a requirement to optionally exclude a2, how to modified the code? ( with map or flatMap is also acceptable)

Further more, say if I have M possible future needs to be aggregated like above, and N of M could be optionally excluded against some flag (biz logic), how should I handle it?

thanks in advance!

Leon

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What do you mean to 'optionally' output b? if (outputB) {... Seq(a,b,c,d) } else {Seq(a,c,d)}?

Comment: Sorry for that. I actually mean "opt out" :) I've changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

In question1, I understand that you want to exclude one entry (e.g B) from the sequence given some logic and in question2, you want to supress N entries from a total of M, and have the future computed on those results. We could generalize both cases to something like this:

```
// Using a map as simple example, but 'generators' could be a function that creates the required computation
val generators = Map('a' -> genA1, 'b' -> genA1, 'c' -> genA3, 'd' -> genA4)
...
// shouldAccept(k) => Business logic to decide which computations should be executed.
val selectedGenerators = generators.filter{case (k,v) => shouldAccept(k)}
// Create Seq[Future] from the selected computations
val futures = selectedGenerators.map{case (k,v) => Future(v)}
// Create Future[Seq[_]] to have the result of computing all entries.
val result = Future.sequence(futures)
```

In general, what I think you are looking for is `Future.sequence`, which takes a `Seq[Future[_]]` and produces a `Future[Seq[_]]`, which is basically what you are doing "by hand" with the for-comprehension.